# tracking 2 objects and giving them different bounding boxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, object-detection, tracking

im trying to adapt this code to my prject in tracking and detection moving object in 
surveillance camera
im trying to work just in 2 classes cars and motorcycle but every time i try i get error
this is the code 
im using the colors green and red for the bounding box

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('tab20b')
colors = [41,42]


for track in tracker.tracks:
            if class_name == "car" :
              if not track.is_confirmed() or track.time_since_update > 1 :
                continue 
                bbox = track.to_tlbr()
                class_name = track.get_class()
                color = 42
                cv2.rectangle(img, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])), color, 2)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]-30)), (int(bbox[0])+(len(class_name)+len(str(track.track_id)))*17, int(bbox[1])), color, -1)
                cv2.putText(img, class_name +  "-" + str(track.track_id),(int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]-10)),0, 0.75, (255,255,255),2)
            elif class_name == "motocycle" :
              if not track.is_confirmed() or track.time_since_update > 1 :
                continue 
                bbox = track.to_tlbr()
                class_name = track.get_class()
                color = 41
                cv2.rectangle(img, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])), color, 2)
                cv2.rectangle(img, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]-30)), (int(bbox[0])+(len(class_name)+len(str(track.track_id)))*17, int(bbox[1])), color, -1)
                cv2.putText(img, class_name + "-" + str(track.track_id),(int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]-10)),0, 0.75, (255,255,255),2)
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Please add that to your question.

Comment: if i remove  "if class_name == "car" :"  and   "elif class_name == "motocycle" : "it works but color is always black  even if i change color number and if i go with that same code i get this  error :
  File "object_tracker.py", line 131
    elif class_name == "motorcycle" :
                                                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level